# XSLT remove spaces between the output

Tags: c, xslt

I red several existing questions but they were referring to the spaces that exist in the xml. I am trying to remove the spaces that occur because of the xslt code format.

I Have the following xsl code which should create a c file:

```
#if (defined(<xsl:value-of select="./@Name"/>_TEST1)  || \
 defined(<xsl:value-of select="./@Name"/>_TEST2)  || \
 defined(<xsl:value-of select="./@Name"/>_TEST3) || \
 defined(<xsl:value-of select="./@Name"/>_TEST4) || \
 defined(<xsl:value-of select="./@Name"/>_TEST5) \
                <xsl:if test="CONDITION1">
 || defined(<xsl:value-of select="./@Name"/>_TEST6)  || \
    defined(<xsl:value-of select="./@Name"/>_TEST7)  || \
    defined(<xsl:value-of select="./@Name"/>_TEST8)
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="CONDITION2">
|| defined(<xsl:value-of select="./@Name"/>_TEST9)
                </xsl:if>
)
```

But with the above structure the output is:

```
#if (defined(NAME_TEST1)  || \
 defined(NAME_TEST2)  || \
 defined(NAME_TEST3) || \
 defined(NAME_TEST4) || \
 defined(NAME_TEST5) \

 || defined(NAME_TEST6)  || \
    defined(NAME_TEST7)  || \
    defined(NAME_TEST8)

)
```

Which gives a c error.
The desired output is:

```
 #if (defined(NAME_TEST1)  || \
 defined(NAME_TEST2)  || \
 defined(NAME_TEST3) || \
 defined(NAME_TEST4) || \
 defined(NAME_TEST5) \
 || defined(NAME_TEST6)  || \
 defined(NAME_TEST7)  || \
 defined(NAME_TEST8))
```

**UPDATE1**

I manage to make it work like this, although I don't really understand why it works. Could someone enlighten me?

```
#if (defined(<xsl:value-of select="./@Name"/>_TEST1)  || \
 defined(<xsl:value-of select="./@Name"/>_TEST2)  || \
 defined(<xsl:value-of select="./@Name"/>_TEST3) || \
 defined(<xsl:value-of select="./@Name"/>_TEST4) || \
 defined(<xsl:value-of select="./@Name"/>_TEST5) \ <xsl:text></xsl:text>
            <xsl:if test="CONDITION1">
 || defined(<xsl:value-of select="./@Name"/>_TEST6)  || \
    defined(<xsl:value-of select="./@Name"/>_TEST7)  || \
    defined(<xsl:value-of select="./@Name"/>_TEST8) <xsl:text></xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="CONDITION2">
|| defined(<xsl:value-of select="./@Name"/>_TEST9) <xsl:text></xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
<xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
```

Comment: `xsl:strip-space` perhaps?

Comment: @KerrekSB The `xsl:strip-space` element is used to define the elements for which white space should be removed. I don't have white spaces in my elements so I don't think it would help.

Comment: @AlexandruCimpanu Please post a **reproducible** example - see: [mcve].

Comment: what xslt processor are you using, is this only a stylesheet snippet? Does it behave the same when you build a complete stylesheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is out of context. In general, it's best to use `xsl:text` to write literal text to the output tree.

For example, instead of:

```
defined(<xsl:value-of select="./@Name"/>_TEST2)  || \
```

write:

```
<xsl:text>defined(</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="./@Name"/>
<xsl:text>_TEST2)  || \</xsl:text>
```

Comment: I tried to put the code in between but `xsl:text` must not contain child elements error

Comment: So this is the only solution?

Comment: I don't know. I believe it's the *best* solution.

Answer (score 2):

For info, XSLT 3.0 allows (for example)

```
<xsl:if test="CONDITION1" expand-text="yes">
defined({@Name}_TEST6)  || \
defined({@Name}_TEST7)  || \
defined({@Name}_TEST8){
</xsl:if>
```

You can fine-tune where you want the newlines - it's not clear to me exactly what you require.